# How to use a list in Django query for addition of fields

Tags: django, django-models

I like to perform a Django query like the one below:

```
query = Dbmodel.objects.all().annotate(result=F('fieldname1') + F('fieldname2') + F('fieldname4'))
```

But instead of using the fieldnames directly, I would like to use a list  with the field names:

```
fields = ['fieldname1', 'fieldname2', 'fieldname4']
```

Depending on user interaction the number of fieldnames in the list can variate. Is there a way to do it?

As this is my first question on StackOverflow, please let me know, if my question is unclear or I could improve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `operator.add` to combine the multiple `F` expressions into a single expression, and pass that into the annotation.

It would look like this:

```
import operator
from django.db.models import F

# any amount of fields
fields = ["fieldname1", "fieldname2", "fieldname3"] 

# combine into a single sum
combined_expression = reduce(operator.add, (F(x) for x in fields))

# the new query
query = Dbmodel.objects.all().annotate(result=combined_expression)
```